# Replace page based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries, window.location

I'm trying to redirect pages based on the screen sizes, I have two different index files, one is for a mobile version of the web and the second one is for a web version.

on the web version index file I've included:

```
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 767) window.location.replace("./m/index.html")
        else window.location.replace("index.html")
</script>
```

and on the mobile index page I've included:

```
<script>
    if (screen.width >= 767) window.location.replace("../index.html")
        else window.location.replace("index.html")
</script>
```

The problem is two of these index pages keeps refreshing, the pages aren't loaded.

what seems to be the problem here, appreciate your help.

Comment: Remove `else` part from both the scripts, this is causing to go into infinite loop

Comment: Like Tushar said, else is not needed here. On a side-note, have you considered what the impact of browser resizing would be on this? It would end up refreshing the page each time.

Comment: thanks, but I want the pages to change as the browser size is being dragged to increase. like make it look like its responsive.

Comment: Add the code in a function, and call it on page load as well as on `resize`

Comment: :( how do I do that?

Comment: Google `resize event Javascript`

Comment: CSS media queries are probably the more appropriate tool to use (media query should probably be omitted from the javascripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `resize` javascript event, as Tushar said.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", getTemplate);

CurrentPage = 'DesktopPage';

function getTemplate() {
    if (screen.width >= 767 && CurrentPage != 'DesktopPage') {
        return window.location.replace("desktop.html");
    }

    if (screen.width < 767 && CurrentPage != 'MobilePage') {
        return window.location.replace("mobile.html");
    }
}

getTemplate();
```

This will check your current page and the screen size, because there is no sense to redirect to the Desktop page if you already are in the Desktop page.

---

You also can add more versions, like a "SmallerMobilePage".

```
window.addEventListener("resize", getTemplate);

CurrentPage = 'SmallerMobilePage';

function getTemplate() {
    if (screen.width >= 767 && CurrentPage != 'DesktopPage') {
        return window.location.replace("desktop.html");
    }

    if (screen.width < 767 && CurrentPage != 'MobilePage') {
        return window.location.replace("mobile.html");
    }

    if (screen.width <= 480 && CurrentPage != 'SmallerMobilePage') {
        return window.location.replace("smaller_mobile.html");
    }
}

getTemplate();
```

Comment: but what is someone resize browser manually while on mobile page?

Comment: Yep, you can't resize. So you don't need to put the logic for checking if is in the Mobile Page.

Comment: Yup. I would recommend you using `media queries` and adapt your pages to mobile versions instead using 2 different versions. It's much simpler.